# add mediatory layer of abstraction on Cake\Orm\Table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The reasoning behind my head:

- the desired is not supported yet by [cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#supported-databases)
- the desired db is new db (for me), so my plan is to learn it also to develop some kind of driver for it.
- the possibility to use this db is high on my future project, if it could be a driver or plugin it would be an ease for me when it released it could be ease for cake user.

I just try to create a Table class under my namespace, like so:

```php
// Model/Table/Table.php
namespace Enter\Rql;
  require_once(ROOT. "/vendor/danielmewes/php-rql/rdb/rdb.php");
  use r;
  class Table extends \Cake\ORM\Table
  {
    private $conn= NULL;
    private $db= NULL;

    function initialize(array $config)
    {
      $this->conn= r\connect('localhost');
      $this->setup();
    }

    public function setup()
    {
    }

    public function insert(array $data)
    {

// Model/Table/StudentsTable.php
  require_once 'Table.php';
  use Enter\Rql\Table;
  class StudentsTable extends Table
  {
    // function initialize(array $config)
    // {
    // }

  }
```

but the result is that the insert method is not available in the controller.

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you manually require that `rdb.php` and `Table.php` file, this should all be handled by composer's autoloader!? That aside, how is your autoloader and CakePHP app namespace configured? And how do you load that table class? The namespace looks possibly wrong, at least in the default CakePHP skeleton it would be according to the default PSR-4 setup. Even if you have an autoloader for this that works, having `Enter\Rql` and `Enter\Rql\Table` map to the same folder is straight out calling for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own datasource plugin.

https://ravendb.net/ (assuming this is the one you want) is a NoSQL db system. So you could try to take a look at the https://github.com/tiaguinho/mongodb-cakephp3 an see how similar it is. However, building a complete datasource adapter is a time consuming task.

You certainly want to look at existing implementations. You could check the elastic search plugin as well to get additional input an ideas how this is done.